# Make headings anchor-jumpable

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, navigation

The main feature:

- Headings could have an auto-generated id that could be used to constract a webpage link to an exact location of a lengthy Q/A.
- Such anchors could also be used to navigate within an Q/A itself to its other parts.

Additionally:

- Support for id attribute `<p id="my-id">lorem ipsum</p>` to allow creating arbitrary anchors not bound to headings. The above currently renders as `" lorem ipsum"<p></p>`
- other tags, e.g.: `<hr id="one"/>`, `<br id="two"/>`

**For discussion:**

*Who is responsible for uniqueness of the anchor ids?*

- author should make unique headings if they want to use anchor jumps
- duplicate headings could have an automatic number increment appended

*note: If the anchor id ceases to exist (ie by editing the answer), it will still be possible to navigate to the original Q/A as it is still present in the link (`some-question/<answer-id>#nonexistent-anchor`)*

##### Below this line I present you a *mock Answer* interlaid with my commentary using quotes and code.

Hopefully it should convey the idea.

---

> **Imagine a friend sending you a solution to some issue:**
>
> > "
> > Here is the solution that worked for me. Try this:
> > `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392111/make-headings-anchor-jumpable#solution-a`
> > "
> > ~ some friend
>
> Notice the anchor part in the link. (`#solution-a`)

## Solution A

A very lengthy solution with some more text. blahblah

> The heading above would be rendered with an **auto-generated id**
>
> ```
> <h1 id='solution-a'>Solution A</h1>
> ```
>
> and the link from the friend above would make the page scroll to this exact heading directly.

#### step A1 <sub>(`renderes as <h3 id='step-a1'>step A1</h3>`)</sub>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

#### step A2 <sub>(`renderes as <h3 id='step-a2'>step A2</h3>`)</sub>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

## Solution B

Another very lengthy solution. Such length. wow

> The heading above would be rendered with an **auto-generated id**
>
> ```
> <h1 id='solution-b'>Solution B</h1>
> ```

> Follows example **inter-document** navigation. Useful to link from within an answer to another bit of text already mentioned somewhere else in the answer.
> It uses the classic link syntax `[link text][1]`, however, in the url, you won't place a full address, but just the **hash part**.

Lorem ipsum, See the previous solution `[step 2 of solution A][1]` but this time, replace *something* with *some other thing*.

```
  [1]: #step-a2         <- notice just the hash part
```

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

## Solution C

Yet another solution
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

> Below I attempt to use `id` attribute
>
> ```
> <p id="my-id">lorem ipsum</p>
> <p>lorem ipsum</p>
> ```
>
> which renders just this
>
> ```
> " lorem ipsum"         (<- this actually looks like an error?)
> <p></p>
> <p>lorem ipsum</p>
> ```
>
> See for yourself with devtols / Inspect.

lorem ipsum

lorem ipsum

Comment: Navigate to what? From answer to other answers, from question or answer to its own content?

Comment: Duplicate on MSE https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37894/support-anchor-names-in-posts

Comment: @SamuelLiew Yes, the marked answer addresses the exact same points I do in my question. Thanks for finding that. I am little sad that it's already almost a decade old though :(

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Users can use the auto-generated anchors however they want, either to navigate within one document, or to other answers as well.

Comment: I have a userscript for the adventurous: [Sticky Post Headers & Question Table of Contents](https://stackapps.com/q/7994/9011)

Comment: @SamuelLiew That's an interesting extension, but I am mostly interested in being able to share links to specific sections via an url which should not depend on a userscript. Most other services that use MD already support that. One such example is **github**.

Answer (score -6):

I don't think either solution above is correct. What should be done is: . :

1. Each answer *already has* an id attribute that can be linked. You can see it if you inspect the HTML
2. Just expose that as a link. There's plenty of space beneath the voting chevrons. Just add it in there. When you click on it you get `#<answer-id>` added to the URL in the address bar.

That's it. Now you can just copy and paste from the address bar and you're done.

If you want a fancier solution:

1. Add a "copy" icon below the voting chevrons. When you click it, the #-appended URL gets copied directly onto your clipboard.

Both are easy-peasy to implement. Should be less than an hour to code it.

Comment: There's a "share" button below the answers that does this already, but more neatly.  It doesn't let you link *part* of an answer, though, which is what this requests.

Comment: Awesome. I learned something new today!